# Any suggestions on why the Lock mechanism isn't getting implemented in the below python script?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, synchronization, locking

I'm using multithreading for anonymously login into publicly available FTP sites and listing out the hostnames along with the respective directories. I'm using the threading.lock() method to do the same however it isn't seems to be working and prints hosts and respective directories randomly. Where am I going wrong ? Below is the code I'm running.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import threading
import Queue
from ftplib import FTP

ftpSiteList = [ 'ftp.x.org', 'ftp4.FreeBSD.org', 'ftp.ncsa.uiuc.edu',    'ftp.crans.org' ]
threadsList = []

class workerClass(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,queue,tid):
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)
            self.queue = queue
            self.lock = threading.Lock()
            self.tid = tid
            print "Worker Thread %d reporting for Service !!!"%self.tid

   def run(self):
            self.lock.acquire()
            try:
                    while True:


                                    host = ''
                                    try:
                                            host = self.queue.get(timeout=1)
                                    except Queue.Empty:
                                            print "Worker thread %d exiting. "%(self.tid)
                                            return
                                    try:
                                            conn = FTP(host)
                                            conn.login()
                                            print 'Host: ' +host
                                            print conn.retrlines('LIST')
                                    except:
                                            print "Error in listing HOST "+host
                                            raise
                                    self.queue.task_done()
            finally:
                    self.lock.release()


  queue = Queue.Queue()

  for threads in range(5):
    worker = workerClass(queue,threads)
    worker.setDaemon(True)
    worker.start()
    threadsList.append(worker)
    print "Thread %d started  .."%threads

 for host in ftpSiteList:
    queue.put(host)

 queue.join()

 for threads in threadsList:
    threads.join()

 print "Scanning completed !!!"
```

===========================================================================

## Output is below

```
Worker Thread 0 reporting for Service !!!
Thread 0 started  ..
Worker Thread 1 reporting for Service !!!
Thread 1 started  ..
Worker Thread 2 reporting for Service !!!
Thread 2 started  ..
Worker Thread 3 reporting for Service !!!
Thread 3 started  ..
Worker Thread 4 reporting for Service !!!
Thread 4 started  ..
Worker thread 4 exiting. 
Host: ftp4.FreeBSD.org
Host: ftp.crans.org
Host: ftp.ncsa.uiuc.edu
-rw-r--r--    1 ftp      ftp          5430 Jul 19  2014 favicon.ico
-rw-r--r--    1 ftp      ftp           655 Nov 24  2014 index.html
drwxr-xr-x    3 ftp      ftp             3 Jul 19  2014 pub
226 Directory send OK.
lrwxrwxrwx    1 0        0              10 Jun 14  2012 custom ->         pub/custom
lrwxrwxrwx    1 9865     9865           10 May 24  2012 debian ->    pub/debian
lrwxrwxrwx    1 9865     9865           20 May 27  2012 debian-backports -> pub/debian-backports
lrwxrwxrwx    1 9865     9865           22 May 24  2012 debian-multimedia -> pub/debian-multimedia/
lrwxrwxrwx    1 9865     9865           20 May 24  2012 debian-security -> pub/debian-security/
lrwxrwxrwx    1 0        0              10 Apr 14  2014 events -> pub/events
drwxrwsr-x   27 0        4            4096 Jan 27  2014 git
drwx------    2 9865     9865        16384 Jun 08  2012 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x   14 9865     9865         4096 Nov 26  2013 pub
lrwxrwxrwx    1 9865     9865           11 May 24  2012 ubuntu -> pub/ubuntu/
lrwxrwxrwx    1 0        0              12 Jun 14  2012 videolan ->   pub/videolan
226 Directory send OK.
Worker thread 1 exiting. 
-rw-r--r--    1 12873    floppy        784 Aug 22  1994 .index
-rw-r--r--    1 80       root          663 Jan  7  1995 .message
-rw-r--r--    1 80       root        25819 Dec 29  1994 Brochure
drwx------    2 80       ncsa         2048 Jun 16  1998 Cyberia
drwxr-xr-x    2 12873    root         2048 Aug 22  1994 DTM
drwxrwxrwx    4 root     root         2048 Dec  4  2003 Director
drwxr-xr-x   13 14453    root         2048 Aug 22  1994 Documentation
drwxr-xr-x    9 root     root         2048 Feb  5  1997 Education
drwxrwxrwx    2 root     root         2048 Apr  9  1996 FigLeaf
drwxr-xr-x   13 19099    root         2048 Aug 22  1994 GlobalModels
drwxr-xr-x    8 12873    root         2048 May 17  1996 Mac
drwxr-xr-x   10 12873    root         2048 Feb 15  2002 Mosaic
drwxr-xr-x    5 12873    root         2048 Jan  5  1995 PC
-rw-r--r--    1 80       root        16557 Jan  3  1995 README
-rw-r--r--    1 12873    root         1933 Jan 12  1995 README.FIRST
drwxr-xr-x    5 12873    root         2048 Feb 15  2002 SGI
drwxr-xr-x    4 12873    root         2048 Dec 20  1994 Telnet
drwxr-xr-x    7 12873    root         2048 Aug 24  1994 Unix
drwxrwxrwx   12 root     root         2048 Jan 30  2004 VR
drwxr-xr-x   24 12873    root         2048 May 31  1997 Visualization
drwxrwxrwx    2 root     root         2048 May 20  1996 Vosaic
drwxr-xr-x    6 12873    root         2048 May 16  1997 Web
drwxrwxrwx   24 root     root         2048 Sep 22  2006 aces
drwxr-xr-x   10 12873    root         2048 Aug 22  1994 aff
drwxrwxrwx    2 root     root         2048 Jul 24  2002 aips
drwxrwxrwx   12 root     root        43008 Aug 27 00:30 alg
drwxrwxrwx    4 root     root         2048 Mar 17  2003 benchmarks
dr-xrwxrwx    2 root     root         2048 Apr 21  2006 bin
drw-r--r--    2 15332    wheel        2048 Jan 27  1999 chemistry
drwxrwxrwx   68 root     root         4096 Apr 12  2007 cosmic
drwx------    3 80       ncsa         2048 May 24  2002 dbalsara
drwx------    2 80       games        2048 Dec 23  1997 emerge
drwxr-xr-x    3 80       root         2048 Jun 27  2006 etc
drwxr-xr-x    4 80       sys          2048 May 12  2009 incoming
drwx------    3 80       games        2048 Aug 25  1997 java
drwx------    2 80       games        2048 Jul 22  1997 joule
drwx------    7 80       ncsa         2048 Jun  5  2000 lca
drwxrwxrwx    2 root     root         2048 Nov  9  2001 lib
drwxrwxrwx   16 root     root         2048 Sep 25  2003 media
drwxr-xr-x   14 12873    root         2048 Nov 21  2001 misc
drwxrwxrwx   21 root     root         2048 Mar 16  2001 ncsapubs
drwxrwxrwx   14 root     root         2048 Oct  3  2007 netdev
drwxrwxr-x   31 12984    wheel        2048 Mar 19  2015 outgoing
drwxr-xr-x    4 12873    root         2048 Dec 21  1999 sc22wg5
drwx------    2 nobody   games        2048 Mar 15  2007 security
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root         2048 Dec 22  1999 x3j3
Worker thread 3 exiting. 
226 Transfer complete.
Worker thread 2 exiting. 
Host: ftp.x.org
-rw-r--r--   2 ftp      ftp           479 Nov  6  2001 banner2
lrwxrwxrwx   1 ftp      ftp             7 Oct  9  2005 bin -> usr/bin
drwxr-xr-x  34 ftp      ftp          4096 Nov  6  2001 contrib
d--x--x--x   2 ftp      ftp          4096 Aug  8  2001 dev
drwxr-xr-x   2 ftp      ftp          4096 Oct 12  1998 digest
d--x--x--x   3 ftp      ftp          4096 Aug  8  2001 etc
-rw-r--r--   1 ftp      ftp          3075 Oct  7  1998 GettingBroadway
-rw-r--r--   1 ftp      ftp          3075 Oct  7  1998 GettingR6.3
-rw-r--r--   1 ftp      ftp          1847 Feb  1  1999 GettingR6.4
-rw-r--r--   1 ftp      ftp          1378 Aug 24  2000 GettingR6.5.1
-rw-r--r--   1 ftp      ftp          1229 Apr 24  2001 GettingR6.6
-rw-r--r--   1 ftp      ftp           301 Dec 22  2005 GettingR6.7
-rw-r--r--   1 ftp      ftp           396 Dec 22  2005 GettingR6.8
-rw-r--r--   1 ftp      ftp           396 Dec 22  2005 GettingR6.9
-rw-r--r--   1 ftp      ftp           396 Dec 22  2005 GettingR7.0
-rw-r--r--   1 ftp      ftp           195 Dec 30  2004 MIRROR.README
drwxrwxr-x  36 ftp      ftp          4096 Jun 30  2013 pub
drwxr-xr-x  56 ftp      ftp         24576 May  4  2001 R5contrib
drwxr-xr-x   2 ftp      ftp          4096 May  4  2001 rcsfaq
-r--r--r--   1 ftp      ftp          1571 Dec 22  2005 README
lrwxrwxrwx   1 ftp      ftp             6 Nov 27  2005 README.txt ->      README
d--x--x--x   5 ftp      ftp          4096 Aug  8  2001 usr
-rw-r--r--   2 ftp      ftp           479 Nov  6  2001 welcome.msg
226 Transfer complete
Worker thread 0 exiting. 
Scanning complete !!!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your `lock` variable is an instance variable, and not a  variable shared between your threads as you want it to be.

You defined the variable as an instance variable when you wrote

```
def __init__(self, queue, tid):
    ...    
    self.lock = thread.Lock()
    ...
```

You can check this by

```
def __init__(self,queue,tid):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
        self.tid = tid
        print "%d !!!"% id(self.lock) # all threads print different ids
```

For each of the threads, this gives a different `id`, meaning that they are independent objects.

What you want is to create a class variable. Class variables are shared across all instances of the class.

```
class workerClass(threading.Thread):
    lock = threading.Lock()
    def __init__(self,queue,tid):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
        self.tid = tid

    def run(self):
        lock.acquire()
        # do stuff
        lock.release()
```

Comment: Got your point. Kudos for highlighting the error. Along with the solution being pointed by you,  I also tried declaring the lock outside the class. Is it fine or are there any cons ?

Comment: Logically declaring your lock outside the class should work fine. However, declaring it within your class makes more sense, since only the instance of that class are using it. Also, if this helped, could you mark it as correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import threading
import Queue
from ftplib import FTP

ftpSiteList = [ 'ftp.x.org', 'ftp4.FreeBSD.org',    'ftp.ncsa.uiuc.edu','ftp.crans.org' ]
threadsList = []


class workerClass(threading.Thread):
    lock = threading.Lock()

    def __init__(self,queue,tid):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.queue = queue
    self.tid = tid
    print "Worker Thread %d reporting for Service with the lock id %d!!!"%(self.tid,id(workerClass.lock))

def run(self):
    try:
        workerClass.lock.acquire()
        while True:


            host = ''
            try:
                host = self.queue.get(timeout=1)
            except Queue.Empty:
                print "Worker thread %d exiting. "%(self.tid)
                return
            try:
                conn = FTP(host)
                conn.login()
                print 'Host: ' +host
                print conn.retrlines('LIST')
            except:
                print "Error in listing HOST "+host
                raise

            self.queue.task_done()

    finally:

        workerClass.lock.release()
queue = Queue.Queue()

for threads in range(5):
    worker = workerClass(queue,threads)
    worker.setDaemon(True)
    worker.start()
    threadsList.append(worker)
    print "Thread %d started  .."%threads

for host in ftpSiteList:
    queue.put(host)

queue.join()

for threads in threadsList:
    threads.join()

print "Scanning completed !!!"
```